# How to check a checkbox in a PDF programmatically

Tags: c#, pdf, checkbox

I am experimenting with Essential Objects' EO.PDF component for .NET
and can't find a way to "check" a checkbox in an existing PDF document.

I have posted to the EO forum already, but I think that it may not be a vendor specific issue.

```
// I've tried 'Yes', 'On', 'True', and even 'X' 
// but it does not show a tick in the output PDF.
doc.Fields["chk1"].Value = "???";
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used EssentialObjects' EO.PDF personally, but according to the [documentation](http://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/4/eo.pdf.pdfcheckboxfield.value.aspx) there seem to be two ways to set it: you can either set the `Value` property to "1", or set the boolean `Checked` property to true.  (I think you'd have to cast the field to a `PdfCheckBoxField` to use the latter method.)